# grep -v issue to get line counts for over a thousand files (individual line counts)

Tags: grep

I need to use this command on a VCF file:

```
grep -v "#" {name of VCF file} | wc -l
```

This gives me number of lines without the "#".

But my problem is that I have a lot of files in a directory that I need individual line counts for. SO I NEED the Number of lines without "#" in each file.

When i do this: `grep -v "#" *.vcf* | wc -l`, the pipe just sums up all file's lines without the #. I need to know line counts individually for each file. I cannot manually pipe each file's lines ( I have over a thousand files). Can anyone suggest how I can get line counts for each file. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `grep -c` instead of piping to `wc -l`:

```
grep -c -v -- '#' *.vcf
```

Beware that if there's only one vcf file in the current directory, its name won't be output, you'll only get the count.

To work around that, with the GNU implementation of `grep` or compatible you can add the `-H` option.

```
grep -Hcv -- '#' *.vcf
```

With other implementations, you can always add `/dev/null` to the list and pipe to `tail -n +2` to remove it:

```
grep -c -v -- '#' /dev/null *.vcf | tail -n +2
```

(though you'll lost `grep` exit status in the process unless you set the `pipefail` option of your shell where supported).

If on the other hand, you only want each count without the file names, use `-h` instead of `-H` with GNU `grep`, or use a loop with `grep` implementations that don't support `-h`:

```
for file in *.vcf; do grep -cv '#' < "$file"; done
```

Or to report failures in the overall exit status:

```
(
  ret=0
  for file in *.vcf; do
    grep -cv '#' < "$file" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

If you get a *argument list too long* error, you can split the list into several `grep` invocations with the help of `xargs` (here assuming GNU tools):

```
printf '%s\0' *.vcf | xargs -r0 grep -cvH -- '#'
```

Or if using `zsh` with its `zargs`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -r -- *.vcf(Nn.) -- grep -cvH -- '#'
```

(here also using its glob qualifier feature to restrict to regular files (`.`), use numeric sort order for the file list (`n`) and avoid errors if there's no vcf files (`-r` with `N`)).